# Request for retrieving email message and expanding attachments doesn't retrieve referenceattachments

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail, graphserviceclient

retrieving email message expanding attachments doesn't retrieve referenceattachments (that we upload using upload & share from onedrive)
If an email contains only reference attachments the list would return empty

```
GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/messages/{id}/attachments
```

I tried following request

```
GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/messages/{id}?$expand=attachments
```

The above request gets all the attachments however reference attachments are not included in the result.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below URL

GET [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/{id}/?$expand=microsoft.graph.itemattachment/item](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/%7Bid%7D/?$expand=microsoft.graph.itemattachment/item)

See the docs for more info - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/attachment-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-4-expand-and-get-the-properties-of-an-item-attached-to-a-message-including-any-attachment-to-the-item

Comment: it will also not work as we do this when we know the attachment id, tried this and resulted into this 
"code": "BadRequest",
 "message": "Parsing OData Select and Expand failed: Encountered invalid type cast. 'microsoft.graph.itemAttachment' is not assignable from 'microsoft.graph.message'."

Comment: the problem is this:
Let's say I email a user by attaching a file (upload to onedrive & share) this kind of attachment is know as 'reference attachment'. So when I request to get the message along with attachments, message is retrieved but it does not contain the attachments

Comment: however if I attach a file by using "browse from computer" this kind of attachment is know as fileattachment, So when I request to get the message along with attachments, it will have that attachment listed as well

Comment: I hope the above comments will help you in understanding the problem